# Oracle SQL ORA-00933 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to receive a column with the last value of `MODLOGIN` from c source but I still receive an error:

> ORA-00933 command not properly ended.

```
WITH a AS (SELECT

a.UIDINSTANCEID, a.APPLICATIONNUMBER,a.FIELD3,a.APPLICATIONDATE,a.FIELD12,a.FIELD6 , a.FIELD9, a.FIELD16, a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL

FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATION a

WHERE

(a.field6 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE' or a.field9 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE')

AND a.field12 >= :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_START AND a.field12 <= :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_KONIEC AND a.HDB_LAST = 'Y'),



c AS (SELECT c.UIDINSTANCEID,c.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL,c.MODDATE,c.MODLOGIN

FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG_1R c



),

h AS (SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL, MAX(NAME) AS NAME FROM

(SELECT h.SYMBOL,h.NAME FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h WHERE h.DICTID = 839 AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y'

UNION ALL

SELECT h.SYMBOL,h.NAME FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h WHERE h.DICTID = 1226 AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y'

UNION ALL

SELECT h.SYMBOL,h.NAME FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h WHERE h.DICTID = 1285 AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y')

GROUP BY SYMBOL)





SELECT

a.APPLICATIONNUMBER AS NR,

to_number(LPAD(a.FIELD3,3)) AS TECHNICZNY_NR,

h.NAME AS NAZWA_DYSPOZYCJI,

TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.APPLICATIONDATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA_REJESTRACJI,

TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.FIELD12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATA_ROZWIAZANIA,

a.FIELD6 AS GRUPA,

a.FIELD9 AS GRUPA2,

a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL,

a.FIELD16 AS SLA,

MAX(c.MODLOGIN) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY c.UIDINSTANCEID,c.MODDATE) as MODLOGIN

FROM HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATION a

GROUP BY c.UIDINSTANCEID

LEFT JOIN HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG c

ON a.UIDINSTANCEID = c.UIDINSTANCEID

LEFT JOIN h ON LPAD(a.FIELD3,3) = h.SYMBOL
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` in combination with `GROUP BY` makes no sense.

Comment: You tagged `mysql` but exception comes from Oracle. Where do you run query?

Comment: Also, `GROUP BY` cannot come before additional joins, and the `group by` is incomplete

Comment: Sorry by mistake, I used Oracle sql

Comment: Do you have any idea how should I fix this groupon by and left join sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

You need your `JOIN`s before your `GROUP BY`.

```
WITH a AS (SELECT a.UIDINSTANCEID, a.APPLICATIONNUMBER, a.FIELD3, a.APPLICATIONDATE, a.FIELD12, a.FIELD6, a.FIELD9, a.FIELD16, a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL
          FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATION a
          WHERE (a.field6 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE' OR a.field9 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE')
          AND a.field12 BETWEEN :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_START AND :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_KONIEC 
          AND a.HDB_LAST = 'Y'),
    c AS (SELECT c.UIDINSTANCEID, c.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL, c.MODDATE, c.MODLOGIN
          FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG_1R c),
    h AS (SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL, MAX(NAME) AS NAME 
          FROM (SELECT h.SYMBOL, h.NAME 
                FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h 
                WHERE h.DICTID = 839 
                AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT h.SYMBOL, h.NAME 
                FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h 
                WHERE h.DICTID = 1226 
                AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT h.SYMBOL, h.NAME 
                FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h 
                WHERE h.DICTID = 1285 
                AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y')
        GROUP BY SYMBOL)
SELECT a.APPLICATIONNUMBER AS NR,    
to_number(LPAD(a.FIELD3,3)) AS TECHNICZNY_NR,
h.NAME AS NAZWA_DYSPOZYCJI,
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.APPLICATIONDATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA_REJESTRACJI,
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.FIELD12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA_ROZWIAZANIA,
a.FIELD6 AS GRUPA,
a.FIELD9 AS GRUPA2,
a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL,
a.FIELD16 AS SLA,
MAX(c.MODLOGIN) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY c.UIDINSTANCEID,c.MODDATE) AS MODLOGIN
FROM HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATION a
LEFT JOIN HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG c ON a.UIDINSTANCEID = c.UIDINSTANCEID
LEFT JOIN h ON LPAD(a.FIELD3,3) = h.SYMBOL
GROUP BY c.UIDINSTANCEID, a.APPLICATIONNUMBER, to_number(LPAD(a.FIELD3,3)), h.NAME, TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.APPLICATIONDATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.FIELD12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), a.FIELD6, a.FIELD9, a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL, a.FIELD16
```

This may also work to remove the need for the `UNION ALL`s.

```
WITH a AS (SELECT a.UIDINSTANCEID, a.APPLICATIONNUMBER, a.FIELD3, a.APPLICATIONDATE, a.FIELD12, a.FIELD6, a.FIELD9, a.FIELD16, a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL
          FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATION a
          WHERE (a.field6 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE' OR a.field9 = 'ZAJECIA_EGZEKUCYJNE')
          AND a.field12 BETWEEN :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_START AND :DATA_ROZWIAZANIA_KONIEC 
          AND a.HDB_LAST = 'Y'),
    c AS (SELECT c.UIDINSTANCEID, c.NEWSTATUSSYMBOL, c.MODDATE, c.MODLOGIN
          FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG_1R c),
    h AS (SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL, MAX(NAME) AS NAME 
          FROM (SELECT h.SYMBOL, h.NAME 
                FROM HDD99_DSA_UNU.V_DICTIONARYVALUES h 
                WHERE h.DICTID IN (839, 1226, 1285)
                AND h.HDB_LAST = 'Y')
        GROUP BY SYMBOL)
SELECT a.APPLICATIONNUMBER AS NR,    
to_number(LPAD(a.FIELD3,3)) AS TECHNICZNY_NR,
h.NAME AS NAZWA_DYSPOZYCJI,
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.APPLICATIONDATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA_REJESTRACJI,
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.FIELD12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS DATA_ROZWIAZANIA,
a.FIELD6 AS GRUPA,
a.FIELD9 AS GRUPA2,
a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL,
a.FIELD16 AS SLA,
MAX(c.MODLOGIN) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY c.UIDINSTANCEID,c.MODDATE) AS MODLOGIN
FROM HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATION a
LEFT JOIN HDD99_DSA_UNO.V_APPLICATIONEVENTLOG c ON a.UIDINSTANCEID = c.UIDINSTANCEID
LEFT JOIN h ON LPAD(a.FIELD3,3) = h.SYMBOL
GROUP BY c.UIDINSTANCEID, a.APPLICATIONNUMBER, to_number(LPAD(a.FIELD3,3)), h.NAME, TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.APPLICATIONDATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(a.FIELD12),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), a.FIELD6, a.FIELD9, a.APPLICATIONSTATUSSYMBOL, a.FIELD16
```

Comment: Tahnk you @Matt but now I receive error:                                       
 ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

*Cause:   

*Action:

Error at Line: 24 Column: 8

Comment: Thank you Matt, now it runs! but I am waiting for results 15min + now for a really short data range (2 days). Is it caused by this large group by ?

Comment: @adamoszczak without knowing your tables/data etc its difficult to say, but it will add time to your query yes.

Comment: Too much data? try limiting to a select few values?

Comment: So I limited It to 2 days and it is still processing... Something must be wrong in code probably

Comment: 2 days doesn't mean anything without context? 2 days could have billions of rows for all i know. its impossible to day without more information